# MC3300R Mobile Computer integration document (Android) not able to find

Tags: android, mobile, mobile-application, zebra-scanners

I'm looking for document MC3300R Zebra device (Mobile Computer). I'm using 2.0.2.82 RFID SDK and able to integrate RFD8500. I'm using bluetooth connection for RFD8500. Now I want to integrate MC3300R, I don't know what kind of integration will work here because not able to find any particular doc for it.